# Questions about DLLs

Tags: .net, security, debugging, dll

Alright I'm pretty new to programming and stuff and I'm now trying to code some basic programs in c#.

Now I'm basically working on a little thing that's basically a DLL that allows anyone to use the program as long as the program specifies and no longer.

I've already kinda figured out how i'll do the code, i'll do some checks and then either return true or false to the exe if the beta is still valid or not.
But I don't really know how DLLs work completely, I know that there's programs that can kinda look into DLL code. So here's my questions:

- Couldn't someone just change or rip off the source code and change the value to always be true? and if they could, is there any way to prevent this?
- How do you actually properly debug a DLL file? Now I'm just writing the code in an exe which I plan to later move to a DLL, but that can't be right.

Also any other tips are welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're basically doing is writing [DRM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management), and that's a game you can't win. No matter what you do, your access control measures *can* and *will* be cracked, if someone cares enough.

There are about 2 things that I know of that are much harder to crack:

- Hardware dongles
- Authenticating with a remote server (Multiplayer games and Steam are very good at this, Windows and Office are slightly worse at this).

And regarding debugging DLLs, yeah, you basically debug them using a program which uses the DLL.

Comment: Well I like the idea but the programs should also be available offline.

Comment: Then the best you can do is make it hard enough. If someone wants to change it and tries hard enough, then she can do it. Some people do crackmes for sport, y'know.

Comment: I see, Alright thanks, I think I'll use a combination of my old system and authentication. I'll leave this question open for a while so I can hear some other suggestions as well

Comment: There's also obfuscation, which makes it more time consuming (but not impossible) to reverse engineer a DLL.

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_injection

Answer (score 0):

1. DLL and EXE are the same thing with one major difference the exe(cute) can run by its own, DLL(dynamic link library) however needs an exe(or some other executable file) file to "run" it.
2. the genaral state of mind in programing is that every layer of protection is crackable, after saying that there are some tools that helps making it harder to do reflection( taking machine language and transforming it back to C# ) like steven worte (+1).
3. as for debugging the DLL you can use VS unit tests, very useful tool.